# Sorting search results array by number of matches?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a basic search function for my site. Realising that the most useful search displays the page with the most counts of the terms given, I coded the following:

```
function search()
{
    $this->page = preg_replace('/[^\w \"\']/i', '', trim($this->page));
    preg_match_all('/"(.[^"]+)"|([\w]+)/i', $this->page, $terms);
    $terms=array_unique($terms[0]);  // scrub duplicate search terms
    $tsql="SELECT reviewSummary, reviewFullText, game.gameName FROM review LEFT JOIN game ON review.gameID = game.gameID "; 
        $constraint="WHERE";
        foreach ($terms as $term)
        {
            $term=str_replace('"','',$term);
            $tsql.=" $constraint (reviewSummary LIKE '%".$term."%' OR reviewFullText LIKE '%".$term."%' OR game.gameName LIKE '%".$term."%')";
            $constraint="AND";
        }
        $tsql .= "AND game.isPublished = 'y'";
        $result = $this->sql->db_query($tsql);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $gameName = stripslashes($row['gameName']);
                $content = strip_tags($row['reviewFullText']) . ' ' . $row['reviewSummary'];
                $counter = 0;
                foreach($terms as $term)
                {
                    $term=str_replace('"','',$term);
                    preg_match_all("/($term)/i", $content, $matches);
                    foreach($matches[0] as $m)
                    {
                        $counter++;
                    }
                }
                $found["Games"][$gameName]=$counter;
            }   
        }
        print_r($found);
}
```

Works great. What it *doesn't* do is order the results in according to which has the most matches. I'm not sure how to sort the resulting array to achieve this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at at [uasort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) which can sort an associative array using a user-defined comparison function. Something like this should do it...

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1;
}

uasort($found["Games"], 'cmp');
```

Comment: That was *fast*. Thank you Paul!